# Soil organic carbon datasets

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, mapping, soil

I am analyzing soil organic carbon stocks for several states in the US. I am interested in data sources (free or paid at this point). I have checked some freely available sources of data, including the ISCN, ISRIC, RaCA, SSURGO, OpenLandMap. Is there any other source which can provide with extra information? I need to prepare a dataset, with the most precise and updated information, to be used in a model. This is being pretty hard to achieve with the databases I mentioned, either because of its spatial resolution/accuracy (OpenLandMap/RaCA) or because or their temporal resolution (ISCN, ISRIC).

Comment: Have you checked with OpenData.SE?

Comment: Posted right now.